# Kill process from node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I've used the following code to run some process which is working OK,my question is if there any option to kill this process on demand (by code)

```
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    var cmd = 'any command';

    exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
....
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var child = exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) { ... });

// When you want to kill it:
child.kill(SIGNAL);
```

See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal).

Comment: Thanks, what is signal and from where should i get it?\

Comment: @JohnJerrby the documentation suggests reading the manual page for `signal` (`man signal` if you're on Unix, not sure if Windows has something similar). FWIW, the signal is optional, it will default to sending `SIGTERM`.

Answer (score 1):

exec returns a childProcess object

you can kill it using childProcess.kill([signal]) - signal is SIGTERM if not specified