# Node.JS closing another application

Tags: node.js

I've been working on a program and it requre's restarting a certain application with Node.JS
I know Python is able to close another app but is Node.JS able to?

For example if a function is triggered I need it to close Spotify from the Node.JS process.

Thanks!

Comment: This is kind of a weak question, Node and Python are both scripting libs. So as with Python, you would need to find a native wrapper for the process you are looking to manage or a more generic node-based process manager. 

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835187/node-js-process-restart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js process restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835187/node-js-process-restart)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676917/kill-process-from-node-application

If you are looking more to do it based on PID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal

> The `process.kill(pid[, signal])` method sends the `signal` to the process identified by `pid`.

---

Of course, this assumes you already know the pid of the process you want to end.  If you don't you'll have to [find it](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=find%20process) first.